# Is it legal to publish a game that uses a youtube tutorials code?

Tags: java

I am working on my noughts and crosses game, and I am following a youtube tutorial,
It is helping me write the Java code.
I am wondering I could to publish it to the website itch.io legally.
The game would be free.
Thankyou.

Comment: You can, but why would you? You didn't technically made it just because you copied code

Comment: Because im modifying some of the code

Comment: I believe this might be a case by case basis. Anything on Youtube that is a tutorials is educational and, if i am not mistaken, falls under a different set of rules. This means that some tutorials will display programming that is actually patented, whilest others dont. To be safe i would try to find out if the programming presented in the tutorial is patented or copyrighted.